# What physical processes can convert dark matter into dark energy?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, dark-energy

In this news article, it is mentioned that it could be the case that some physical processes convert dark matter into dark energy

http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2014/nov/18/is-dark-energy-eating-dark-matter

What physical processes could lead to such a transformation, if any?

Comment: Have a look at this discussion on the paper itself, not media popularizations .http://motls.blogspot.gr/2014/11/how-paper-about-dark-matter.html

Answer (score 1):

No we cannot determine the nature of dark matter or dark energy. So the nature of dark matter is still unknown. If we define the nature of dark matter, then we can say it may convert, or not.