# Does this analogy with matter and energy hold?

Tags: soft-question, dark-matter, dark-energy

Matter is to energy as dark matter is to dark energy.

Is that statement correct? If not, is there any relationship, that we know of, between dark matter and dark energy?

When I say there is an analogy. I kind of imply that some version of $E=mc^2$ holds for the "dark" equivalents.

Comment: Briefly: no. Not at all.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33466/.

Comment: The only thing they have in common is the word "Dark". "Dark matter" is stuff out there that's heavy but we can't see it and, of course, it is equivalent to some energy, like all matter is. "Dark energy" is like a silent explosion filling empty space causing galaxies to accelerate away from each other, ever faster.

Comment: Please explain where you see the connection. Just naming two random concepts and asking if they are related is an *unclear* question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I know you're trying to help, but it's almost comical. Both of the "random" things I named share half of their characters. It's like asking why an up quark is different from a down quark, the concepts were certainly not named randomly.

Comment: @Zach466920 up and down quarks are both the same *thing* (quarks) with different *properties* (upness and downness). Dark energy and dark matter are two different things with a similar property - "darkness," meaning we can't see them. Sharing a word between two names for two objects doesn't mean much about the nature of the conceptual objects; otherwise we'd be trying to explain how dark chocolate is just the dark matter version of chocolate, since those also are both called "dark."

Comment: Other questions along this incorrect line of thinking: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156333 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185509

Comment: @KyleKanos I was asking a question, my line of thinking was to defer to the people here...thankyou for the reference.

Comment: @Asher really? That's tautological. You basically said 'blue is the property of blueness' what is blue? In the same way, saying dark matter is "dark" shows a similar lack of understanding, especially with that chocolate example...

Comment: @Zach466920 if I speak of a "dark corner," I am using a noun modified by an adjective. If I speak of "dark energy" or "dark matter," I am using a phrase that has a different meaning than you'd get from just parsing individual words. A corner is made of matter, but a dark corner is not made of dark matter or lit by dark energy. It might help to clear up the confusion if we do away with the 'dark' terminology and stick to other, less ambiguous terms like 'WIMPs' and 'cosmological constant.'

Comment: @Asher Ya, no...you say " (quarks) with different *properties* (upness and downess)" FYI, those "adjectives" are marked as nonexistent in the English dictionary by my phone. Well obviously, WIMPS have energy. The 'cosmological constant' is not energy. Pretty simple right? I only asked this question to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No-one knows what dark matter and dark energy are, so any comments on your question are necessarily speculative.

Having said this, dark matter is generally considered to be just matter and the adjective *dark* is not meant to signify anything mysterious but merely that it doesn't interact with electromagnetic radiation or charge. The most popular suggestion is that dark matter is made up from the supersymmetric partners of the well known particles, and while we don't know exactly how these will behave we expect them to be described by a relatively straightforward extension to the Standard Model. For example dark matter particles and antiparticles would annihilate to produce photons, just like electrons and positrons. Likewise, we hope (though it's a fading hope) that the Large Hadron Collider will be able to make supersymmetric particles by colliding protons in which case we can make dark matter from non-dark matter.

So if our guess is correct then non-dark matter and dark matter are just different forms of the same thing, and as far as we know neither has any connection to dark energy.